# How can I get vim to include suffixes in <cfile>?

Tags: vimscript, filesystem

In part of a plugin I'm slowly building, I use `<cfile>` to get the file pointed by the word under the cursor and then do something if it points to a directory, or open the file pointed to otherwise (so unless the word under the cursors points to a directory, it's supposed to behave exactly like `gf`). It all works fine, except for suffixes.

`help <cfile>` in vim says:

> `<cfile>`    is replaced with the path name under the cursor (like what `gf` uses)

but while `gf` will include a possibly auto-detected `suffix`, this doesn't seem to be the case in `<cfile>`. Is there some kind of workaround for this?

In case it helps clarify my question, here's the relevant code excerpt:

```
  1 function! now#BufEnter() "{{{                                          
  2 " behaviour of <enter> while on now files (mapped on ftplugin)         
  3   execute "silent! normal! :set suffixesadd=" . g:NOW_suffix . "\r"    
  4   let l:dest = expand("<cfile>")                                       
  5   if isdirectory(l:dest)                                               
  6     " if pointing to a directory, update and enter index file there    
  7     execute 'normal! :cd ' . l:dest . "\r"                             
  8     call now#MakeIndex()                                               
  9   else                                                                 
 10     " otherwise edit the file, whether it exists or not                
 11     execute 'normal! :e ' . l:dest . "\r"                              
 12   endif                                                                
 13 endfunction "}}}
```

Line 3 was added for debugging purposes only, copied from elsewhere. The added suffix is flawlessly detected by `gf`, but not with the keymap pointing towards the above function (as the comments in the code mention, it is the `<enter>` key). When no suffix is needed, the code works as expected: do the directory stuff if need, or edit the  pointed file, creating it if necessary.

Comment: What happens if you replace line 11 with just `:normal! gf` ?

Comment: @VanLaser : With just `normal! gf` regular `gf` is called and suffixes are indeed respected *but* if the file does not exist, it is not created (as per comment in line 10). Note that I don't expect a non-existing file to be created with a "guessed" suffix, but I do expect an existing file to be opened if there is one, seeking it with the environment suffixes. Maybe it is these two behaviours (lookup with suffix / create if not existing) that are actually incompatible with each other?

Comment: In any case, thanks for the suggestion, @VanLaser. I'm going to use that variant for now, sacrificing the "create file if it doesn't exist" in favour of "follow the link with an optional implicit suffix if a possible file does exist". Actually, I could add another `if` to act differently if the file does not exist, and then: problem solved. Nevertheless, the help on <cfile> is a bit confusing (as <cfile> is clearly **not** quite *like what `gf` uses*)

Comment: You're welcome :) Good to see you found a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prompted by the comment fron @VanLaser, I thought it may be possible to somehow discriminate the behaviour with an `if filereadable()` to decide whether invoking a regular `gf` or an `:edit` in order to work around the limitations of `<cfile>`. However, there's a catch: I don't know which file to seek for readability before invoking `gf`. So finally, after `try`ing a bit, here's a solution... with a `catch`.

```
 1 function! now#BufEnter() "{{{
 2 " behaviour of <enter> while on now files (mapped on ftplugin)
 3   execute "silent! normal! :set suffixesadd=" . g:NOW_suffix . "\r"
 4   let l:dest = expand("<cfile>")
 5   if isdirectory(l:dest)
 6     " if pointing to a directory, update and enter index file there
 7     execute 'normal! :cd ' . l:dest . "\r"
 8     call now#MakeIndex()
 9   else
10     " otherwise edit the file, whether it exists or not
11     " N.B: this is a bit tricky, because <cfile> does not detect an optional
12     " suffix, as discussed in the following Q/A topic:
13     " https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9627/2058
14     try
15       " if a file can be found, with optional suffix, open it
16       normal gf
17     catch
18       " otherwise, create the file pointed to
19       execute 'normal! :e ' . l:dest . "\r"
20     endtry
21   endif
22 endfunction "}}}
```

A nice side-effect of this is being able to actually **add** a specific suffix upon creation (not shown in above code, which, for reference, is only trying to modify the question's code enough to answer the actual question).

Comment: Nice! I wonder if you could use `:find <file>` instead of `gf`. Also I'm not sure you need the `execute 'normal! :e ...` construct on line 19 (why not directly `execute 'e ...`?) It's cool to see the URL of *this* question in the answer, it gives it an air of self-referencing :) (you may want to use the short form, for aesthetic reasons (?): http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9627/1800)

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize there were shortened URLs available. Thanks for the tip @VanLaser. Just edited accordingly. As for the `execute 'normal! ...` construct, I use it very often since learning about it in [LearnVimscripTheHardWay](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/30.html). It is particularly safe against a lot of annoyances. In this case, after testing now, with a direct `execute 'e ...` I get an extraneous `^M` added to the filename, which is not the case with `execute 'normal!`

Comment: As for `:find`, I don't think it would make things any simpler than "can `gf` open something? if yes, do it, if no, then create the most reasonable alternative".